# Hide Menu If Customer is not Logged In. And Show when Login

Tags: topmenu

I want to hide the menu when user is not logged in. And Show when It Logs in. I did the following code.

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
}

public function getCustomerIsLoggedIn()
{
    if($this->customerSession->create()->isLoggedIn() == false)
    {
        $this->redirect->setRedirect('customer/account/login');
        $this->logger->info("Not Logged in");
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Problem is It doesn't show the menu after login. Only show when I clear cache. Same when I log out It doesn't disappear. After cache clean It disappear.  Please help.

Comment: Please share your whole code. Where did you add the above code? (Block, Helper, Controller, or any Other Model)

Answer (score 1):

Following code you can check customer login or not anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

From controller

```
$customerSession = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below for show/hide menu but make sure you are overriding your theme files correctly

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
           // customer login action
            echo $_menu;
        }
```

if this not working, that means, in your case, there is a problem with the cache or your theme files that save this in cache settings.

Try running the compilation command: `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and check again.

you need to override the file:
app/code/VENDORNAME/MODULENAME/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
 */
private $httpContext;

public function __construct(
    ....................................................
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ....................................................
) {
    ....................................................
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    ....................................................
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
    return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
}

public function getCustomerIsLoggedIn()
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        // Customer
    } else {
        // Guest
    }
}
```